# Following positive semi-definitness from matrix norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

How can I follow the following?

$$||A||_2 \le \sigma > 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A -\sigma I \mbox{ is positive semi-definit}$$

I always get it the other way around, i.e. that $\sigma I - A$ is positive semi-definit.

Comment: And you are right. But this requires the assumption that $A$ be symmetric (if real), or self-adjoint.

Comment: You are right, it's $\sigma I - A$, not $A - \sigma I$ (unless $A = \sigma I$, when both are positive semidefinite).

Comment: Thanks! Fast and encouraging comments :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got it right. Obvious counterexample $A=0.5 I$ with $\sigma=1$